# Setting Data Validation range from rows labels on pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, named-ranges

I'm trying to set the range for data validation in a cell called "RepName" using the list of row labels from a Pivot Table.  The pic below illustrates the range I want to use for the data validation.

[image]

This code is not working:

```
Dim PTRange As Range
Set PTRange = Range(Range("$B$185"), Selection.End(xlDown))

ActiveSheet.Range("RepName").Select
  
     With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=PTRange"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "Value must be on the list"
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = "Insert line into table on sheet DrpDwnValues and enter value into blank line"
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

I've also tried "=INDIRECT(""PTRange"")" - and no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Replace ``Formula1`` in ``Add Type`` to be ``Formula1:="=" & PTRange.Address``

Comment: Why do you need vba, you can use the data-source of this pivot for data validation too? Can you share a screenshot of how your data is structured? I mean the cell address

Comment: Thank's Elio Fernandes!  You're a genius!  I knew it was a basic syntax problem.

Comment: To answer your question Gangula, the row labels in the pivot table are the equivalent of "SELECT UNIQUE" statement in SQL.  The data source has hundreds of lines and I'm using the pivot table labels to summarize a single instance of each value in the field.